# is there any tool to package an Adobe AIR to exe?

Tags: air, installation, exe

I am creating an adobe air application, I want to  package the AIR file  into an exe file with customs installer properties..Is there any tool available??? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiXEdit is an editor for XML source files for the Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset to build MSI and MSM setup packages

Answer (score 1):

Adobe AIR application is designed to run with Adobe AIR Runtime. If you have the original FLA file, you can pack it the EXE ( in `Publish Settings > Win Projector` ) in Adobe Flash.